# Why is it showing me an error when generating schema using drizzle ORM

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm making an application in NodeJs and I can't generate the tables using DrizzleORM, I've tried everything and it always gives the same error. I'm using Typescript. NeonDB database.

**schema.ts**

```
import {pgTable, doublePrecision, integer, text, serial, varchar } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

export const $products = pgTable('products', {
  id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
  product_name: varchar('product_name', { length: 100 }).notNull(),
  product_category: varchar('product_category', { length: 100 }).notNull(),
  product_description: text('product_description').notNull(),
  product_price: doublePrecision('product_price').notNull(),
  product_stock: integer('product_stock').notNull(),
  product_image: text('product_image').notNull(),
});

export const $orders = pgTable('orders', {
  id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
  customer_email: varchar('customer_email', { length: 100 }).notNull(),
  total: doublePrecision('total').default(0),
});

export const $order_items = pgTable('order_items', {
  id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
  order_id: integer('order_id')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => $orders.id),
  product_id: integer('product_id')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => $products.id),
  quantity: integer('quantity').notNull(),
  total: doublePrecision('total').default(0),
});

export type Product = typeof $products.$inferInsert;
export type Order = typeof $orders.$inferInsert;
export type OrderItem = typeof $order_items.$inferInsert;
```

**drizzle.config.ts**

```
import type { Config } from "drizzle-kit";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({
  path: ".env",
});

export default {
  driver: "pg",
  schema: "./src/db/schema.ts",
  out: "./drizzle",
  dbCredentials: {
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL!,
  }
} satisfies Config;
```

**Error Terminal**

```
drizzle-kit: v0.19.13
drizzle-orm: v0.28.6

No config path provided, using default path
Reading config file 'D:\e-commerce-native\server\drizzle.config.ts'
D:\e-commerce-native\server\node_modules\drizzle-orm\pg-core\index.mjs:1
import { L as PgColumnBuilder, e as entityKind, N as PgColumn, n as TableAliasProxyHandler, R as pgTableWithSchema, U as pgViewWithSchema, X as pgMaterializedViewWithSchema, i as is } from '../alias-cf8e03cd.mjs';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .mjs] (D:\e-commerce-native\server\node_modules\drizzle-kit\index.cjs:8627:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\e-commerce-native\server\src\db\schema.ts:1:74)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production ts-node src/index.ts",
    "generate": "drizzle-kit generate:pg",
    "migrate": "ts-node migrate"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.28.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "postgres": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.18",
    "@types/node": "^20.7.0",
    "@types/pg": "^8.10.3",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.19.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

I can't find the error, in fact I can't even understand what's wrong